# Equivalent of SPI_GETMOUSESPEED in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to get the mouse speed (or what you might call mouse acceleration, tracking speed/acceleration - it goes by many names) in OSX. Is this possible using Cocoa in Objective-C? The equivalent call in Win32 in C++ would be passing `SPI_GETMOUSESPEED` to `SystemParametersInfo`.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `hypot(delta-x,delta-y)/(latestEvent.timestamp-previousEvent.timestamp)`?

Comment: @James Bucanek, nope there's a setting for it and I want to read it. Although speed = distance / time, when you adjust the mouse acceleration, the reported distance for a given movement changes, so it's not possible to calculate this value by triangulating NSEvent data.